# Using Regular Expression in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I've more than 100 files all including texts like:

```
<option value="Text">Text</option><option value="Text2">Text2</option>
```

I want to use reguler expression in dreamweaver for changing these like:

```
Text
Text2
```

When I tried to do that with ? matching all of the texts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this search and replace function in Dreamweaver to edit source code?

Comment: sure, and i've selected regex already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search:

```
<option +[^>]*>([^<]*)</option>
```

Replace:

```
$1\n
```